# angularjs save rendered values in html in a variable

Tags: html, angularjs, spring-mvc

I hope someone can help me with this, It's a strange question maybe as I didn't find an answer online.

I call the database and retrieve a list (in json) of items.
Then in angularjs,I render this list by extracting relevant pieces of data(name,age,etc) and show it properly in a table as a list of rows.

I have then an edit button that takes me to another page where I want to put a dropdown list.
What I want to know if is possible to add to that dropdown list the rendered list I previously created in my previous page.
is it possible to save the previously rendered list in a variable and then use that variable in the dropdown?

thank you

Comment: It sounds like you what you want to do is reuse data (the data which you used to populate the dropdown list), which can be accomplished in several different ways. Truly global data can be saved on the $rootScope but you may want to look at implementing a service to handle your data and have that service injected into your controllers.

Comment: I think for my problem rootscope or services can't be used

Basically lets say that I have a list of people
in my first view i use ng-repeat and other function to nicely show each person age,name,surname and address ,without showing the profession.
in the second view I don't want to render the people list again, I want to be able to use the rendered list in the first page and use it in the dropdown of the second page.
so in the code where I'm using ng-repeat and rendering each person, is it possible inside there to initialize a list variable and save each person in the way I'm rendering it?

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? If I understand you correctly, you want to inject the rendered HTML from your first view into your second view. What would be the benefit and why not allow Angular to render the list again?  As an aside, if nested views are the structure that you actually wish for then consider Angular-UI Router which supports them.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the list within a controller and make this data availablte to this dropdown, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to query for the list, add the list to the template, get the list from the template and render somewhere else, I'd suggest query for the list, save the list in a service , and then when you want to use that list again, get it from the service.  Something like:

#### service:

```
var services = angular.module('services');

services.factory('getListService',['$http',function($http){
    var getListOfStuff = function(){
        //call to database
        return //your json
    };

    var extractNameAgeEtc = function(){
        var myListOfStuff = //get list of stuff from $http or database
        var myListOfNameAgeEtc = //make a list of tuples or {name,age,etc} objects
        return myListOfNameAgeEtc;
    };

    return {
        extractNameAgeEtc : extractNameAgeEtc
    };
}]);
```

#### controllers:

```
angular.module('controllers',['services']);

var controllersModule = angular.module('controllers');

controllersModule.controller('tableRenderController',['getListService','$scope',function(getListService,$scope){
    //use this with your table rendering template, probably with ng-repeat
    $scope.MyTableValue = getListService.extractNameAgeEtc();
}]);

controllersModule.controller('dropdownRenderController',['getListService','$scope',function(getListService,$scope){
    //use this with your dropdown rendering template, probably with ng-repeat
    $scope.MyDropDownValue = getListService.extractNameAgeEtc();
}]);
```